# React form can be submitted twice despite conditional render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, formik

I have a React application coupled to Redux. There is a component rendering a form wrapper (a custom implementation of Formik), while the form inputs themselves are rendered by a child component.

(Not the exact code, but gets the point across.)

```
...
render() {
  const {
    config,
    updateContactDetails,
    errorMessages,
    contactDetails,
    previousFormValues,
    isUpdating,
  } = this.props;
  const { apiBaseUrl, fetchTimeout, globalId } = config;
  const initialValues = previousFormValues || getInitialContactDetailsValues(contactDetails);

  if (isUpdating) return <Spinner />;
  return (
      <Form
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validate={(values) => validate(values, errorMessages)}
        onSubmit={(values) => {
          updateContactDetails(apiBaseUrl, globalId, values, fetchTimeout); // dispatch action
        }}
      >
        <ContactDetailsForm content={content} />
      </Form>
  );
}
...
```

When you click the submit button in `ContactDetailsForm`, the value of `isUpdating` in the Redux store is set to true. As you can see above, that causes the the form to be replaced with a spinner component. However, it is somehow possible to submit the form twice by clicking the button twice.
How can this be? Could there be re-render happening before the one that replaces the form with the spinner? I know I can solve the problem by passing `isUpdating` into `ContactDetailsForm` and using it to disable the button, but I still want to illuminate the cause.

EDIT

The reducer looks something like this, in case it helps:

```
case UPDATE_CONTACT_DETAILS_START: {
  return {
    ...state,
    errorUpdatingContactMethods: {},
    hasUpdatedContactDetails: false,
    isUpdating: true,
    contactDetailsValues: action.values,
  };
}
```

Comment: Are you able to click the button twice before it is rerendered to show the Spinner?

Comment: formik has isSubmitting property

Comment: I don't think passing `isUpdating` to the `ContactDetailsForm` would work. `ContactDetailsForm` shouldn't even render if `isUpdating` is true. Can you share the onClick function, redux action/reducer? That might help illuminate the problem.

Comment: @EinarÓlafsson Yes, that is the mystery. You would think the form would be replaced by the spinner before I could click the button a second time.
@Maria Somehow passing ```isUpdating``` does work, having tried it. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Let me see if I can post the reducer code.

Comment: You should probably set an internal state that is triggered as soon as you click the button to disable it. Sound like the Redux changes are happening to slowly to rerender the component in time.

Comment: What do you want to happen once the form is submitted and you have a response from the server?

Comment: @DavidMacKintosh that is so bizarre. I'd love to understand how that can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead set a `disabled` property on the button based on the `isUpdating` prop. It might be that it's just a race condition.

Comment: Yes, I thought it might be a race condition somewhere. Are you able to explain in more depth how it might happen in this case?

Comment: @DavidMacKintosh I'm not exactly sure, where does isUpdating come from?

Comment: It is set in the Redux reducer, which is triggered by an action despatched when you click the submit button. The value from the store gets mapped to a prop in a higher level component, and then passed as a prop to the component above.